Power Automate - 401 Unauthorized at Sharepoint Connector after it worked successfully
My company uses Office365 and I just setup a small power automate cloud workflow to set my Teams presence status:

The workflow this action is using worked fine yesterday, but today I get this error from sharepoint:
{
  "status": 401,
  "message": "clientRequestId: b963572e-dc3c-430d-81f5-c63dcf2b1089",
  "source": "https://presence.teams.microsoft.com/v1/me/forceavailability",
  "errors": []
}

As the HTTP PUT call worked, I assume the reason is an expired token issue or something similar. I signed out and in multiple times in "power automate". I also opened the "sharepoint app" in Office365 (whatever you're supposed to do with it) which worked fine.
The sharepoint connector in power automate also seems to be happy:

Any ideas how to get the sharepoint connection running again ?

cross-posted also on the power-automate forum: https://community.powerplatform.com/forums/thread/details/?threadid=66a1880d-1556-ef11-a317-6045bdeda78e

Creating a new connection did not work for me. I have been using this approach in Logic Apps and tried rebuilding as a Flow as well, but same result in both cases. 401 on the SharePoint Connector. Seems to have broken for me between the 12th of September and 13th of September.

It happens for me again since this week. Not sure if it's a company thing or MS SharePoint im general (once) again

I was able to get mine working again by selecting "Change Connection" in the SharePoint step (making the PUT to presence.teams.microsoft.com).
I added my own account in a second time and saved and tested and it worked fine.

Open the Flow
Click the Update my Note step
Click "Change Connection" at the bottom of the parameters window.

Credit to where I originally found how to set a status message:
https://damobird365.com/teams-status-update-via-power-automate/ (see comments).

I could not fully follow your steps but deleting + re-creating the sharepoint connection worked for me as well. I mark this as the answer.
For the record, these were the steps I did:
Open https://make.powerautomate.com. Inside my flow: Connections -> Edit -> Connections in use -> delete my sharepoint connection. In general overview: Connections -> Sharepoint -> delete my sharepoint connection here, re-create my sharepoint connection incl. login
To verify I successfully ran the workflow via the UI for testing.

I've experiencing this same issue at my company, I've opened a support ticket last week.
We find out with the Microsoft support, that there are service degradation caused by migrating SharePoint Online 2013 to SharePoint Online.
This migration issue is responsible for the Unauthorized error we are experiencing.
They're "actively" investigating this with the SharePoint team.
Hopefully they solve the problem soon. I'll be in touch as soon as I have more updates.
The SharePoint team solved the problem today. They notified me through Entra. To solve the problem, you need to reauthenticate/replace the previous connector with a new one.

Thanks for sharing these insights

The SharePoint team solved the problem today, they notified me through Entra. To solve the problem, you need to reauthenticate/replace the previous connector with a new one.
